# How do i run my ionic android app on an emulator without installing/running the android studio?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, android-emulator, emulation

Android studio is too heavy and slows down my pc for development. i am an ionic developer and i only need the android emulator to have a better test environment for my mobile application. I only make use of the android studio because i am trying to set up the virtual emulator following the steps in this video [Ionic 3 Tutorial #16 Run app on Android Emulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWrKakQOCYE)

I will like to know if there is another way out to test and run my ionic app either on a real or virtual android emulator. I will like to know if i can run the emulator through my vs code or a lighter IDE

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up the emulator already it is enough to execute "ionic cordova run android" in Visual Studio Code.

VSCode than checks for physical devices connected. If not, it will take the emulator.

Or you could use another emulator like Droid4X or BlueStacks.
=> Build the APK (ionic cordova build android) and install it on one of those.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be use `ionic serve` to run it in the browser then in the console activate `Toggle device toolbar` is not android emulator but might be useful for mobile debug.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this will work while developing, but at the end of the day, I want to build and test my app either on a real/virtual device.

Comment: Then other option it's by using an external emulator like genymotion.